# Jython How to stop script from thread?

Tags: multithreading, jython

I'm looking for some exit code that will be run from a thread but will be able to kill the main script. It's in Jython but I can't use java.lang.System.exit() because I still want the Java app I'm in to run, and sys.exit() isn't working. Ideally I would like to output a message then exit. 
My code uses the threading.Timer function to run a function after a certain period of time. Here I'm using it to end a for loop that is executing for longer than 1 sec. Here is my code:

```
import threading
def exitFunct():
    #exit code here
t = threading.Timer(1.0, exitFunct)
t.start()
for i in range(1, 2000):
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you had to, you could call [`mainThread.stop()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29). But you shouldn't.

[This article](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) explains why what you're trying to do is considered a bad idea.

Comment: hm understood. so are you saying there is no way to safely kill the whole script from a thread? I just want the exitFunct to be able to kill the script since the for loop will be running for too long.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kill the current process and you don't care about flushing IO buffers or reseting the terminal, you can use `os._exit()`.

I don't know why they made this so hard.